# Object Oriented Programming Python - Class properties

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, scope

I am trying to understand class properties in Python OO (Object Oriented).

Let's say I have the following code.

```
    class Testing():
        surname = "Doe"

        def __init__(self):
            print(surname)
```

If we print `surname`, as shown above, it will throw the following error: `NameError: name 'surname' is not defined`. So, how is this class property accessible from outside or inside the class?

Comment: OO programming has no effect on local variables in Python.

Comment: Local variables have nothing to do with class properties.

Comment: `print(email)` or `print(surname)` ?

Comment: @Barmar I have just changed the title. Thanks for that!

Comment: `self.surname='Doe'` should make it available

Comment: `print(surname)` let me edit it.

Comment: Local variables work inside class definitions the same way they work everywhere else: they are available locally and not outside whatever scope they are in (but can be accessed from inner scopes).

Comment: Displays the three cases you use to print

Comment: The question still says "I am trying to understand about local variables in Python, specifically in OOP".

Comment: @Barmar well, now it says "Object Oriented Programming Python - Class properties" but again, this has nothing to do with OOP, or class properties for that matter.

Comment: `surname` is not a class property, class attributes must be part of `self.surname`, `surname` is different to `self.surname`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga He changed the title, he didn't change the text of the question.

Comment: @eyllanesc to be pedantic, `self.surname` would be an *instance attribute*. Class-level attributes belong to the class, instance attributes belong to the instance.

Comment: I think you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules) q/a.

Comment: Yes, you're right :P

Answer (score 2):

`surname` is only available inside the `__init__` method. If you want to access it anywhere else you should do `self.surname = 'Doe'` or `Testing.surname = 'Doe'`. Note that `self` is a reference to the instance.

Usually class attributes are declared inside the class like this:

```
class Testing:
     surname = 'Doe'
```

You could access them and/or reassign them by using `Testing.surname`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code must read as

```py
    class Testing():
        surname = "Doe"

        def __init__(self):
            print(self.surname)  # <<< note `self.` prefix
```